# How do you show a sheet programmatically in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, google-maps, google-maps-markers, swiftui, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm still new to Swift so this may be apparent to some more seasoned developers, but I'm having trouble getting a form sheet programmatically.

For context, I'm building an app using SwiftUI & Google Maps that displays a bunch of markers on a map. Each marker represents a location so when a user taps on a marker an infowindow appears with details about the location. What I'm trying to do now is show a form sheet with the full details of a location when it's infowindow is tapped, but am having trouble figuring it out.

-

Google's documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/protocol_g_m_s_map_view_delegate-p.html#ae1614978aef680d671a6a95da8e13bf7) says to use the following function to handle when an infowindow is tapped:

```
// Function to handle when a marker's infowindow is tapped
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapInfoWindowOf didTapInfoWindowOfMarker: GMSMarker) {
        print("You tapped a marker's infowindow!")
        return
    }
```

Ive tried using the method described in the link [here](https://blog.appsbymw.com/posts/how-to-present-and-dismiss-a-modal-in-swiftui-155c/) to display a sheet when a marker's infowindow is tapped, but cant figure out how to change a boolean variable declared in a View using the function I've shown above^:

**Does anyone know how to change a variable declared within a View from its respective UIViewController, so that I can display a sheet using the method detailed in the link above?**

**Or does anyone know a better way to get a sheet to appear programmatically in Swift/SwiftUI?**

Comment: I'm confused by your question. When the user taps on the info window, what exactly do you want to happen, a view to pop up modally over the map or to modally present a view controller?

Comment: As `UIViewController` is not a SwiftUI View, you communicate between the views through a coordinator. Maybe this tutorial helps you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bmc_bbmRS5w

Comment: @bsod Im trying to get a modal to appear over the map. This is an example of the functionality Im trying to achieve: https://blog.kaltoun.cz/swiftui-presenting-modal-sheet/  The reason I mention a UIViewController is because the function Google documentation says to use when an infowindow is tapped is within a UIViewController